# Fitting KDE with scikitlearn and pandas to plot. However, distributions lie outside the range of data

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, scikit-learn, probability

I am fitting a distribution of scores ranging from 1-13 for a set of data using scikitlearns KDE functions and Pandas plot.kde.

I have set the bandwidth with a gridsearchCV method. However, when the distributions are plotted the range of values reaches to -2.5 and 17.5. These are outside the range of data which is 1-13.[image: Distribution of scores fitted with Gaussian kernel]
I have attatched an image of the distribution itself and will present some code below:

```
plot_m = df_match.plot.kde(bw_method = 0.6842105263157895)
```

My questions is, how do I go about setting boundaries for Kernel Density estimators such as this? The probability of scores being outside the range of data should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel density estimates typically make use of Gaussian bumps, which have unbounded support. (Support is the set over which a density is nonzero.) A kernel density estimate is just a linear combination of kernels, so the k.d.e. will also have unbounded support if the kernels do.

My advice is to just construct a truncated density which is restricted to the known allowable range for the data. A truncated density is defined to be zero outside the allowable range, and proportional to the original, non-truncated density within the allowable range. The constant of proportionality is just 1 - (mass excluded from the allowable range).

I don't know if pandas or sk-learn has anything built in to handle truncated densities, but it's not any big deal to implement it yourself.

By the way, if your data are actually integers, and variable of interest can't actually be a noninteger, you can't do any better than just making a histogram which has one bin per integer in the range 1 to 13.

This is a good question, but probably more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any idea where I can start when it comes to implementing a truncated density myself?

Comment: One implementation can be found here: https://github.com/robert-dodier/riso/blob/master/src/riso/distributions/Truncated.java There's not much to it; you just need to calculate the tail mass to be excluded and then divide by (1 - (tail mass)) to normalize the density on the allowable region. The Truncated class which I've linked to is just a wrapper around some other, arbitrary density; the wrapper handles the stuff about remembering the allowable region and normalizing factor, and implements some operations on the truncated density in terms of the original. Let me know if you have questions.